# How do I display the next n future entries?

Tags: channel-entries

All,

I am trying to display the next *n* future entries for a channel. The query I'm using is posted below, but I've realized that since I limit the entries in the channel entries query, the *if* statement applies to the limited group of five entries. Rather than producing the next five entries.

Instead, I'm looking for a query that will:

1. Pull the entries for a channel
2. Determine whether or not the entry occurs in the future
3. Display the next five upcoming entries.

I am working on someone else's site without FTP access to load a plugin, so I'm hoping to do this within the template.

My current code:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
  channel="blocks" 
  show_future_entries="yes" 
  dynamic="on" 
  orderby="entry_date" 
  sort="asc" 
  disable="pagination|member_data|trackbacks" 
  limit="5"}
     {if entry_date > current_time}
       <li>
         {entry_date format="%l at %g:%i %a"}: 
         {block-venue}
           {block-events show_future_entries="yes"}
             <a href="{path='events/{url_title}'}">{title}</a>
           {/block-films-events}
       </li>
     {/if}
     {if no_results}<li>See you next year!</li>{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would simple adding of `start_on` parameter help you?

```
 start_on="{current_time format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'}"
```